# What is the purpose of having a newer python version in ansible remote nodes?

Tags: ansible

Let's say if your remote host has python version 2.7. What difference does it make having 2.7 version vs. a newer version like 3.6 in the remote node? Does it make execution of playbooks faster? Same for the control node - What difference the python version makes other than some modules not being compatible with older python versions ?

Comment: Both 2.7 and 3.6 are past end-of-life...

Comment: @JiříBaum Past end of life means what? Would the playbooks not work fast either from control or on remote node or security patching is not supported? I copied a file using file module using 2.7 python on controller node and I think 2.6 on remote debian 6 node. I guess my main question is not answered which was what difference python 3.7 and 3.9 make vs 2.7 and 3.6? Is it only security and module support related?

Comment: Past end-of-life means that they are no longer supported by the official maintainers of python; they won't get security or other bugfixes. Many module authors take their cue from this and drop support for those versions around the same time. Python versions 3.7-3.10 are currently supported in python, and usually by other modules.

Comment: Each new version of Python has some new features and other improvements; most of those won't be relevant to using Ansible, unless you're writing plug-ins or similar. They are also typically faster, but again that won't be relevant to using Ansible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Both versions 2.7 and 3.6 of Python are past end-of-life, so support for both of them is likely to be variable. Many modules have dropped support soon after end-of-life, and others may drop support at any time.

  In principle, neither 2.7 nor 3.6 get security updates any more, although that may not be important if all ends of the connection are in any case trusted. However, if your systems have Python 2.7 and 3.6, other parts may also be past their respective end-of-life dates, and those may be more security critical.
- Speed of execution is unlikely to be a big difference, most likely not noticeable; the biggest delay will in any case be the network round-trips.

Comment: So updated python is mainly for security and module support? Both on control and remote?

Comment: Yeah, using outdated Python will be increasingly a hassle as time goes on. In terms of new features and improvements in Python, including speed improvements, those won't be very relevant to using Ansible, unless you're writing plug-ins or similar.